# How to add field to custom view of SugarCRM 7

Tags: sugarcrm, custom-view

I have same problem as of [How to add standard field to custom layout of SugarCRM 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364493/how-to-add-standard-field-to-custom-layout-of-sugarcrm-7)

I have created a custom view(followed these steps http://www.insightful.com.au/sugarcrm-how-do-i/creating-custom-button-sugar-7) in SugarCRM7 but not getting how should I add standard fields to this layout

I am new to SugarCRM7 and seeking for help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use metadata to provide the list of fields and then use the {{field}} Handlebars helper in your template to insert them into your HTML.

To see examples of how to use field helper see dashablelist.hbs or preview.hbs in Sugar 7.5.

Comment: Hi Matt , Thanks for the help !! Apologies for late reply !